# How can i iterate a ArrayDeque in reverse?

Tags: java

How can i iterate a ArrayDeque in reverse?

I would normally do this for an array but it's not indexable.

```
for (int i = delegate.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {}
```

thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the method `descendingIterator()` to get an iterator that iterates the `ArrayDeque<T>` in reverse.

```
Iterator<T> it = arrayDeque.descendingIterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    // do something with it.next()
}
```

Comment: May want to use generics instead of raw types.

Comment: Doesn't work in Kotlin. Do you know the equivalent? Unable to find it.

Comment: @SarahMultitasker: For `kotlin.collections.ArrayDeque`, [`asReversed()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-reversed.html#asreversed) should do the trick. It doesn't create a new, reversed copy of the list. The original is wrapped with a Decorator/View, that points the index to the reversed position in the original list. See the [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/924c28507067cbfbf78a6509ea89eabe496e34ca/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/ReversedViews.kt).

Comment: @SarahMultitasker It seems to me that you might be doing addFirst() to add elements to the ArrayDeque. Why not just do addLast() and negate the need to reverse when you loop through?

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 21, simply using [`Deque.reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html#reversed()):

```
for (int i : arrayDeque.reversed()) {}
```

**Note:** It returns a reverse-ordered [view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#view) of this collection.

Additional details in [JEP 431: Sequenced Collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

The elements will be returned in reverse order from last to first.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */

class List {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // creating a TreeSet 
      TreeSet <Integer>treeadd = new TreeSet<Integer>();

      // adding in the tree set
      treeadd.add(1);
      treeadd.add(13);
      treeadd.add(17);
      treeadd.add(2);

      // create descending iterator
      Iterator iterator;
      iterator = treeadd.descendingIterator();

      // displaying the Tree set data
      System.out.println("Descending order: ");     
      while (iterator.hasNext()){
          System.out.println(iterator.next() + " ");
      }
   }    
}
```

Comment: That's not an ArrayDeque.