# Adding Queue elements into another queue

Tags: java, interface, queue, temp

So I added this condition to add elements to a variable temp and run it through a recursive loop but it gives an error message that would be shown if the queue is empty, NoSuchElementException. Would it be easier to create another Queue instead of temp and place elements inside that or some other way.

```
 public QueueInterface<T> reverseQueue() {
    T temp = dequeue();
    Queue<T> a = new Queue<T>();
    if (a.isEmpty()) {
        temp = dequeue();
        a.enqueue(temp);
        reversed();
    }
    Stack<T> b = new Stack<T>();
    while(!a.isEmpty()){
        b.push(a.dequeue());
    }
    while(!b.isEmpty()){
        a.enqueue(b.pop());
    }
    return a;
}

  public Queue(Queue<T> other) { //creates shallow copy
    int i = 0;
    while (!other.isEmpty() && i < other.size()) {
        this.enqueue(other.peek());
        other.enqueue(other.dequeue());
        i++;
    }
}


  public T dequeue() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    else {
        nElems--;
        T element = front.getData();
        front = front.getNext();
        if (front == null) {
            rear = null;
        }
        return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to reverse the entire queue?

Comment: since you are returning a QueueInterface, you will have to either create a new Queue or create a new QueueView which is a View into the original Queue. The first option is far simpler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760832/how-can-i-iterate-a-arraydeque-in-reverse

Comment: I'm utilizing a stack to reverse the queue my problem is that I can't seem to utilize my other methods to fill a queue with elements.

Comment: Please post all your code.  It's hard to understand exactly what you're doing